# Український аналог вислову "накрыться медным тазом"

Tags: переклад, from-russian, фразеологізми

Який аналог російського фразеологізму [«накрыться медным тазом»](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC) українською?

Згідно зі [сторінкою російського Вікісловника про слово «накрыться»](https://ru.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&oldid=11730366) (яка, однак, пояснює й увесь вислів теж), цей вислів має три різні значення:

1. Зазнати краху (потерпіти крах).
2. Зламатися, зіпсуватися, стати несправним (непридатним).
3. Загинути.

Цікавить здебільшого перше значення.

Comment: Я був би щасливий, якби Ви й власний варіант ([піти прахом](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64040188#64040188)) теж оформили як відповідь. Але якщо через наше ставлення Ви втратити ентузіазм (або ж просто не маєте часу) — я теж прекрасно це зрозумію. (Також можу оформити це як окрему відповідь самотужки, якщо Вам буде зручніше так.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одразу зазначу, що словосполучення *зазнати краху* і *потерпіти крах* вживають на практиці:

- *зазна(ва)ти крах(у)* — [1687 траплянь у ГРАК-16](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&default_attr=lemma&cql=(meet%20%22%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%22%20%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0(%D0%B2%D0%B0)?%D1%82%D0%B8%22%20-1%201)&showresults=1), наприклад:

  > Він зловтішався зараз, що задуми Сатіапала зазнали краху, — чи можна ще чогось бажати! — а водночас відчув ще гострішу ненависть до свого колишнього шефа (Микола Дашкієв, «Зуби дракона», 1956).

  Також ми бачимо це словосполучення в словниках, наприклад [«Російсько-український словник сталих виразів» І. Виргана та М. Пилинської (1959)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%83&dicts=7&highlight=on).
- *(по)терпіти крах(у)* — [145 траплянь у ГРАК-16](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&default_attr=lemma&cql=(meet%20%22%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%22%20%22(%D0%BF%D0%BE)?%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%22%20-1%201)&showresults=1), наприклад:

  > Але ця унія потерпіла крах в Буковині, яка не зробилася уніатською, а лишилася єдиновірною з Києвом і Москвою (Агатангел Кримський, «Чудовий край», 1940).

  Також ми бачимо це словосполучення в словниках, наприклад [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/terpity).

З вищенаведеного словника Виргана та Пилинської дізнаюся про ще варіанти:

- *провалюватися/провалитися* (з чимось).

  > Але сей Ясєньский провалився з своєю місією… (Михайло Грушевський, «Історія України-Руси», том IX, 1931)
- *уриватися/у(ві)рватися* (комусь щось). Я особисто знайшов небагато траплянь у ГРАК-16 (шукав [так](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&default_attr=lemma&cql=%5Btag=%22.*dav.*%22%5D%20%22%5B%D0%B2%D1%83%5D%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%7C%5B%D0%B2%D1%83%5D(%D0%B2%D1%96)?%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%22&sort=%5B%7B%22skey%22:%22kw%22,%22ctx%22:%220%22,%22attr%22:%22doc.date%22%7D%5D&showresults=1)), серед них:

  > …Він… платив їм тілько малу частину того, що сам заробляв… Ну, та тепер йому урветься (Іван Франко, «Для домашнього огнища», 1892).
  >
  > …Їм урвалося без налогів торгувати та драти шкуру з незаможника (з газети «Спілка», 1924).

  Можливо, це є скороченням від [*у(ві)рвалася нитка* (комусь щось робити)](http://sum.in.ua/s/nytka).

Звісно, *провалитися* може не лише хтось з чимось (наприклад, *людина з місією*), а й щось (тобто сама *місія*). І *зазнати* можна не лише *краху*, а й *невдачі*, *поразки*, *провалу* тощо.

Answer (score 3):

- Дуже плідне тут слово *[нанівець](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53405/359004.html)*, має багато варіантів для різних обставин:

> **оберну́тися наніве́ць (вніве́ць).** Втратити значення, силу, виявитися марним, перестати існувати, пропасти і т. ін. Недавня надія знову **обернулася нанівець**, страх зігнав радість (Панас Мирний); Нежатії ниви **Внівець обернулись**: Тяжке лихо тим судилось, Що з войни (війни) вернулись! (П. Куліш).
>
> **піти́ наніве́ць (вніве́ць). 1.** Виявитися марним, даремним; закінчуватися безрезультатно. Невже пішло все нанівець: бесіди, розмови, читання, робота в гуртках, піонерські збори? (О. Донченко); Хвилина розгубленості надто дорого обійшлася козацькій старшині! Адже ж все **пішло нанівець…** (З. Тулуб); // Пропасти марно. (Рябина:) Не дайте **внівець піти** моїй праці і господарству (І. Франко). **2.** Стати непридатним для чого-небудь; зруйнуватися. Невже через мене оцей палац, оця пишна садиба, оця уся пишнота, оце усе добро стане руїною, **піде внівець?** (І. Нечуй-Левицький).
>
> **схо́дити / зійти́ наніве́ць. 1.** Зменшуватися у розмірах, вазі і т. ін. до повного щезання; зникати. — Як видобули вже лівий клин — він уперся у лупак або граніт; правий, де ви, мабуть, тепер робите, **сходить нанівець.** Від розвилки діаметр руди вужчає (Олесь Досвітній). **2.** Поступово втрачати силу; падати. Авторитет начальника з кожним днем **сходив нанівець** (З газети); — Але й Рябокляч не на своєму місці,— додав Гмиря.— Справді, показний наче був. А тепер **нанівець зійшов** чоловік. Чужим розумом віку не проживеш! (А. Головко).

- Також діло може й на [пси зійти](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53399/357942.html):

> **зійти́ (перевести́ся) на пси. 1.** Поступово втратити свою силу, значення. Тепер наш Борислав зовсім **на пси зійшов!** (І. Франко); Без церкви усяке благе діло **зійде на пси** (Василь Шевчук). **2.** Втратити свої риси, характерні якості; занепасти. — Хіба то дівка? То ж таки ледащо, Усе б співала. Боже успаси! Ми вже й без неї з’їхали нінащо. А з нею геть вже **зійдемо на пси** (Л. Костенко); — Знаю, знаю,— нетерпляче постукав ногою Хмельницький,— **перевівся на пси** ти, Лавріне, шептухами почав цікавитись (Н. Рибак).

- Справа може *[вигоріти](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53394/356330.html)*, а може й ні:

> **ді́ло ви́горіло; спра́ва ви́горіла,** прост. Усе успішно завершилося; все буде гаразд, добре. Я рада Вашим звісткам .. Сподіваюсь, що із “Хліборобом” (газетою) **діло вигорить** (Леся Українка); — Гаразд, гаразд, Андрійку! А, може, раптом твоє **діло й вигорить**,— сказав Бойчук (О. Бойченко); (Залеський:) Дивись ти, яка гонориста. Люблю таких. Але ваша **справа**, добродію Савуляк, тю-тю-тю — **не вигоріла** (В. Собко).

Comment: Ця відповідь заслуговує на більше уваги. (Мабуть вплинуло, що цю відповідь створено пізніше.) Сподіваюся, вона її отримає.